# What's the original function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have this Maclaurin series:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{(n+1)(2n^2+10n+3)}{3(2n+3)!}x^{2n}$. Can someone help me getting its original function? I have tried to get it from $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ but got no result so far. Cheers!

Comment: have you tried plotting partial sums? It might give you an idea of what to look for

Comment: Sorry I just realised I have the wrong series! :-( Will update it very soon. Cheers!

Comment: @AngghaNugraha Please, don't edit your question, but rather ask another question... Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Ah OK! :-)

Comment: @Anggha Nugraha Take a look at my answer and see if it can be useful also for the original function.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: That's actually the right series! Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram alpha gives

$\frac{1}{180x^3}\left(x^5 \  _3F_4(2,2,2;1,1,3,\frac{7}{2};\frac{x^2}{4}) + 180 x^2 \sinh(x)-120x +630 \sinh(x) -510x\cosh(x) \right)$

but this may not be the form you are after

Comment: Sorry I just realised I have the wrong series! :-( Will update it very soon. Thank you very much though! Cheers!

Comment: Can you tell me how to use Wolfram Alpha to get that? :-) Thanks!

Comment: just type sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(2n^2+10n+3)/(3*(2n+3)!)x^{2n}

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Recall that
$$\cosh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!},\quad
\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!},\\
\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+2)!},\quad
\frac{\sinh(x)-x}{x^3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+3)!}.
$$
Now if $P$ is a third degree polynomial and
$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{P(n)}{(2n+3)!}x^{2n}$$
then $f$ will be a linear combination of the above functions.

Just find the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ such that
$$P(n)=
A(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)+B(2n+3)(2n+2)+C(2n+3)+D$$
then
$$f=A\cdot\frac{\sinh(x)-x}{x^3}+B\cdot\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x^2}+C\cdot\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}+D\cdot\cosh(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

The $2n$ is a clue: these are the terms of

$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(k/2+1)(k^2/2 + 5k+3)}{3(k+3)!} x^k$$
for odd $k$, i.e. $(g(x) + g(-x))/2$.  Now relate $g(x)$ to an exponential...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. *Alternatively*, on setting 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \cfrac{(n+1)(2n^2+10n+3)}{3(2n+3)!}x^{2n}
$$ one may multiply $f(x)$ by $x^3$ then one may differentiate as follows obtaining
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left( x \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^3f(x)\right)\right)=\frac1{12}  x^2(x^2+24) \cosh x+\frac1{12}(13x^3-x^2)\sinh x
\end{align}
$$ then integrating reversely one gets

> $$
> f(x)=\left(\frac1{12}-\frac{5}{4x^2}\right)\cosh x+\left(\frac1{2x}+\frac{5}{4x^3}\right)\sinh x.
> $$